# mezzanine cms: can the values of meta fields in the form page be saved in database?

Tags: django, mezzanine

I am new to mezzanine cms. I have some questions about the form page.
In the admin interface, I added a form page. On the bottom of the form page, there is a "meta" section which I can add some fields to the form page I created. My questions are:

1) for the meta fields I added, can I save the values of the fields
    in the database?
   2) can the meta fields be from a database table fields? For example,
    I have a user profile model, can I use the fields in the profile
    model as meta fields in the form page? and how?
   3) what are the purposes of the form page in mezzanine cms?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the values are saved in the database by default. If you can't think of a purpose for a form page, you must not need one.

Comment: thank you, Ryne. But how can I find which table saved the meta fields' values? I need to create a user profile page for users to update not admin to update, so I wanted to create a form page for user profile. How can I user my profile model's fields as  the meta fields on the form page? Thank you!

Comment: The reason I am asking is I created a myprofile model and I added some fields to setting ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_EXCLUDE_FIELDS because I don't want to a user provide many details when he signs up. But if I do that, the fields in ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_EXCLUDE_FIELDS can't be updated by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mezzanine's `Form` page is for when you don't want to define your own model. It dynamically constructs a model to save entered data and potentially email it someplace. This is appropriate if the form is defined by a non-programmer admin or if the only purpose of the form is to collect data and send it somewhere.

However, this is probably not a good choice if the purpose is to use the data in your application. For that, it is better to define your own model and use [django's `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/).